# Specman e: How to print variable's address?

Tags: specman, e

Is it possible to print a variable's address in Specman e, as it can be done in c:

```
printf(" variable address = %d \n", &some_variable);
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do this.
In *e*, there is no concept of pointers and addresses.
Also, if this is a variable that persists across a garbage collection (for example, if it is a field or a TCM local variable), its physical address in memory can change, so in fact it is meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
int a = 10;
printf("%p\n", (void *) &a);
```

Comment: This answer seems irrelevant, the question is about the *e* language, not about C.